# I'm looking to write VBA script for separting text withing a single Excel cell to multiple cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have a long list of publications, with all the data put into one cell. I want to separate the data in each cell into different columns. One for author, title, year, journal, date, etc.

For example, in one cell I have:

Plant RA, Page JP, Bonham JH, Jones JP Stairway to Heaven (1971) Led Zepplin Dec 5;1(39):14802-14084

With name representing authors, Stairway to Heaven representing title, (1971) for year, Led Zepplin for journal name, Dec 5 as date, 1(39) as issue, and 14802-14804 to date.

Although each citation will vary in terms of length and number of authors, etc., would it be possible to automate this process? There are too many variables for some command based on something like `LEFT(B1,SEARCH(" ",B1)-1)`, but I can't help but feel that this must be a problem people often come across. Is a simple solution even possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your string doesn't seem to have a consistant variable like for example every part ends with `,` would it be possible to get that created? Otherwise there seems to be to much variables and as you stated every string is different in lenght and structure.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. I suppose I could insert something like `¦` between each part, and possibly automate that process too. Let's say if that was the case, what would the script look like? Instead of measuring based on character number, could I just pull everything from ¦ to ¦?

Comment: To automate that process you get back to the same issue i just stated. Is the String just in your Excel Worksheet or did you retrieve it from somewhere else first?

Comment: It was retrieved from somewhere else. The data came from a survey, so the users input the strings themselves into the single columns. It would have made far more sense, of course, to have them separate the data on input....

Comment: If you have consistent column delimiters then you can use the Split function to divide up the string. See http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/split.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it depends on how badly your citation formats vary, but one very useful tool for automating complicated string handling is [regular expressions](https://blog.udemy.com/vba-regex/). Here's some code that demonstrates how you could structure one possible solution.  The "Test()" subroutine  will demo the process.

[MSDN Regular Expression Quick Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
Sub Test()
    Dim s(1 To 3) As String
    'Format A
    s(1) = "Plant RA, Page JP, Bonham JH, Jones JP Stairway to Heaven (1971) Led Zepplin Dec 5;1(39):14802-14084"
    'Format B
    s(2) = "Plant RA, Page JP, Bonham JH, Jones JP Stairway to Heaven [1971] Led Zepplin Dec 5;1(39):14802-14084"
    'Unknown Format
    s(3) = "Plant RA, Page JP, Bonham JH, Jones JP Stairway to Heaven (1971) Led Zepplin Dec 5-1(39):14802-14084"

    test_string = s(1)

    MsgBox GetFormat(test_string) & Chr(10) & GetYear(test_string)
End Sub
Function GetYear(ByVal s As String)
    Dim YearPattern As Object
    Set YearPattern = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    YearPattern.Add "FormatA", "\(\d{4}\)"
    YearPattern.Add "FormatB", "\[\d{4}\]"

    F = GetFormat(s)
    If F = "Unknown Format" Then
        GetYear = "Error: Format not recognized"
    Else
        Set Result = FindPattern(s, YearPattern(F))
        n = Result.Count
        If n = 0 Then
            GetYear = "![No Result]"
        ElseIf n = 1 Then
            GetYear = Result(0)
        Else
            GetYear = "![Multiple results]: "
            For Each r In Result
                GetYear = GetYear & ", " & r
            Next
        End If
        GetYear = Clean(GetYear, CType)
    End If
End Function
Function GetFormat(ByVal s As String)
    Set FormatPatterns = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    FormatPatterns.Add "FormatA", ",+.*\(\d{4}\).*;.*\):"
    FormatPatterns.Add "FormatB", ",+.*\[\d{4}\].*;.*\):"

    If FindPattern(s, FormatPatterns("FormatA")).Count > 0 Then
        GetFormat = "FormatA"
    ElseIf FindPattern(s, FormatPatterns("FormatB")).Count > 0 Then
        GetFormat = "FormatB"
    Else
        GetFormat = "Unknown Format"
    End If
End Function
Function FindPattern(ByVal s As String, ByVal p As String) As Variant
    'Argument 1: The string to execute regular expressions on (s)
    'Argument 2: A pattern string to execute (p)
    'Return Value: An array of regular expression results
    Set r = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    r.Global = True
    r.IgnoreCase = True
    r.MultiLine = True
    r.Pattern = p
    Set FindPattern = r.Execute(s)
End Function
Function Clean(ByVal s As String, Optional ByVal CType As String) As String
    'Removes unwanted characters from a string (s)
    'Based on the specified type of string "CType"
    Select Case CType
    Case "Year"
        Clean = Replace(Replace(Replace(s, "(", ""), ")", ""), ": ,", ": ")
    Case Else
        Clean = Replace(s, ": ,", ": ")
    End Select
End Function
```